# How to split word files by the number of characters

Tags: ms-word

Could you anybody help me how to split word file by character!

I can't find any way to split word files by the number of characters on the internet!

Comment: What code have you tried so far?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For example, to split a document into 500-character blocks:

```
Sub SplitDocument()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim Rng As Range, i As Long, j As Long
Const Char As Long = 500
With ActiveDocument
  ' Process each character block
  For i = 1 To Int(.Characters.Count / Char)
    j = j + 1
    ' Get the character block
    Set Rng = .Range((i - 1) * Char, i * Char)
    ' Copy the character block
    Rng.Copy
    Rng.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    Call NewDoc(ActiveDocument, (i - 1) * Char + 1, j)
  Next
  If Rng.End < .Range.End Then
    i = i + 1: j = j + 1
    Rng.End = .Range.End
    ' Copy the range
    Rng.Copy
    Rng.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    Call NewDoc(ActiveDocument, (i - 1) * Char + 1, j)
  End If
End With
Set Rng = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Sub NewDoc(DocSrc As Document, i As Long, j As Long)
Dim DocTgt As Document, HdFt As HeaderFooter
' Create the output document
Set DocTgt = Documents.Add(Visible:=False)
With DocTgt
  ' Paste contents into the output document, preserving the formatting
  .Range.PasteAndFormat (wdFormatOriginalFormatting)
  ' Replicate the headers & footers
  For Each HdFt In DocSrc.Sections(DocSrc.Characters(i).Sections(1).Index).Headers
    .Sections(1).Headers(HdFt.Index).Range.FormattedText = HdFt.Range.FormattedText
  Next
  For Each HdFt In DocSrc.Sections(DocSrc.Characters(i).Sections(1).Index).Footers
    .Sections(1).Footers(HdFt.Index).Range.FormattedText = HdFt.Range.FormattedText
  Next
  ' Save & close the output document
  .SaveAs FileName:=Split(DocSrc.FullName, ".doc")(0) & "_" & j & ".docx", _
    FileFormat:=wdFormatXMLDocument, AddToRecentFiles:=False
  .Close SaveChanges:=False
End With
Set DocTgt = Nothing: Set DocSrc = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: I have followed your instructions, but there is an error that the task cannot be completed. The image below is the error that I get when I execute it https://imgur.com/a/7jbXWCI

Comment: It is impossible to tell from your screenshot what code line that error relates to. Nevertheless, I've revised the code slightly. Try it now.

Comment: Thank you very much, I followed the instructions exactly and it worked.